# any better way to handle pushState and routes?

Tags: angularjs, pushstate, ngroute

Here is a sample up for grabs. It demonstrates use of the pushState api (and popstate event) using ngRoute.

This is a headache mainly because I had to juggle around with events and sensing the correct state post which I had to perform certain actions.

The example used: This is a simple list of movie names with their images and some random about text. The user is prompted to fetch them to see the list. He clicks on one item, and is taken to the view which shows details about the item. When the user hits the browser back button, the same list is loaded, but this time there is a `*` marked against the movie recently visited.

Of course, is there a better way to handle this?...I had to rely on `$rootScope` and `$broadcast`, to finally get my controller to "sense" the popstate event...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, stuff, $window) {
  $scope.fetch = function() {
    stuff.all().then(function(data) {
      $scope.stuff = data.data;
    });
  };

  $scope.$on('hpop', function(e, v) {

    //assume this comes from cache - used factory instead
    stuff.all().then(function(d){
      $scope.sel = v;
      $scope.stuff = d.data;
    });
  });

  $scope.select = function(idx) {
    $window.history.pushState(idx, "", $window.location.href);
  };
  console.log('MainCtrl');
});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/entry/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'entry.html',
      controller: 'EntryCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('EntryCtrl', function($scope, stuff, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.id);
  stuff.get($routeParams.id).then(function(stuff) {
    //console.log(stuff);
    $scope.entry = stuff;
  });
  console.log('EntryCtrl');
});

app.factory('stuff', function($http, $q) {
  var api = {};
  var all = function() {
    return $http({
      url: 'stuff.json'
    });
  };

  api.all = all;

  var get = function(idx) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    all().then(function(dt) {
      d.resolve(dt.data[idx]);
    });
    return d.promise;
  };

  api.get = get;

  return api;
});

app.run(function($window, $rootScope) {
  var state = {
    hasState: false,
    value: null
  };

  $window.addEventListener('popstate', function(evt) {
    console.log('popstate:', arguments);
    if(typeof evt.state === 'number') {
      state.hasState = true;
      state.value = evt.state;
    }
  }, false);

  $rootScope.done = function() {
    if(state.hasState) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('hpop', state.value);
      state.hasState = false;
      state.value = null;
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KjJwqRo253zwoNogGFcL?p=preview

Comment: I would recommend first looking at using ui-router instead of angular-router, since ui-router is a state machine, rather than just a routing engine, and you appear to be trying to track states.

Comment: Claies is absolutly right with ui-router you can pretty much do anything you desire you can listen when the state changes, always know where you are and where you are coming from you can check for urls and dynamicly use views, controller or even predefined paramaters. This definatly is the best choice here. As in your example every movie could be a different state and when he is pressing the back button you know where he came from or you could create your self a recent visited array since you always know the state the user is in